# RegEx Problem: Invalid URL matches, but should not

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string, which matches the following RegEx string. I would like it to not match.

**Test String**: `yahoo.c!om`

**RegEx Pattern**: `[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?`

Using [an online tester](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx), I can validate that "yahoo.c!om" matches. I can't figure out how modify the RegEx pattern to make it NOT match. Does anyone have any ideas? This RegEx stuff makes me want to jump off a building.

Comment: Can you tell use what you **do** you want the Regex to match?  If we don't know this, its possible that the regex won't match what you want it to.

Comment: The clause:

    `(.[\w-_]+)+`

Matches the entire url and the engine will just keep reporting matches from this point.  It would be useful if you could give more information on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Perhaps that clause (@matt.seil) should really be `(\.[\w-_]+)+`?

Comment: Or even `(\.[\w-]+)+` as the underscore already is part of `\w`.

Comment: In addition to what @Bart Kiers said, it looks like you've got some unescaped special characters in your regex. I've looked at it in the edit pane but I can't tell if they were put in there automatically by Stack Overflow. It's also worth noting that the `\w` class includes `_`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` in regex matches any character (other than line breaks). So the `.` in:

```
[\w-_]+(.[\w-_]+)+([\w-.,@?^=%&:/~+#]*[\w-\@?^=%&/~+#])?
        ^
        ^
        ^
```

matches the `!` from `yahoo.c!om`. Escape the `.` to match the literal `.` instead:

```
[\w-_]+(\.[\w-_]+)+([\w-.,@?^=%&:/~+#]*[\w-\@?^=%&/~+#])?
        ^^
        ^^
        ^^
```

That way, `yahoo.c!om` won't match entirely.

You may want to "anchor" your regex with the "start"- and "end-of-input" meta characters (`^` and `$` respectively):

```
^[\w-_]+(\.[\w-_]+)+([\w-.,@?^=%&:/~+#]*[\w-\@?^=%&/~+#])?$
```